# Reduce size of authorization python AWS Lambda@Edge

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I'm trying to implement authorization in my cloudfront distribution. It has worked so far until I ran into size limitation. I'm now running into the cloudfront error message `Max allowed: 1048576`, which is roughly ~1MB. But after installing the `authlib` package the total size is around 6MB. My method for validating tokens look roughly like this:

```
from authlib.jose import JsonWebToken

jwk = get_jwk()
claims_options = {
    "iss": {"essential": True, "value": ISSUER},
    "aud": {"essential": True, "value": AUDIENCE}
}
jwt = JsonWebToken()
claims = jwt.decode(token, jwk, claims_options=claims_options)
claims.validate()
```

The whole thing works beautifully until the size limitation.

My ideas to get around this are:

1. Find another package than authlib that is smaller/more efficient.
2. Write my own code which validates hash signature of JWT (get around the need for authlib package).
3. Write the Lambda in javascript to leverage the [NodeJSfunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-lambda-nodejs-readme.html), which according to docs are efficient in packaging the lambda. In the hopes of that its enough.

Perhaps there are more alternatives, but these are the ones I could come up with which are desirable in descending order. Requesting assistance on either of these options or perhaps totally different solution.

Comment: I think your question is too broad. Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `authlib` package is that a significant part of its size is `cryptography` dependency, which has compiled dependencies on its own. Here are few thought on how it can be approached.

### Solution with less dependencies

One option to consider is trying out a more lightweight package like [`pyjwt`](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt). According to [the documentation](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), pyjwt requires `cryptography` dependency if you want to encode or decode tokens using *certain* digital signature algorithms like RSA or ECDSA. This means that with a lightweight version of `pyjwt` (without `cryptography` dependency) you can use the HS256 algorithm, but not RSA or ECDSA. Without `cryptography`, `pyjwt` library should be below size limit.

I’m not an cryptography expert, but as I understand [HS256-based JWT could be subject to a brute force or a dictionary attack](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/09/28/attacking-jwt-authentication/). Therefore, it is [recommended](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518) to use RS256 or ES256 algorithms instead, which are possible only with `cryptography`.

### Solution with delegating jwt decoding to a different API

An interesting solution on how to use recommended algorithm is shown in [this repository](https://github.com/richardjkendall/cf-edge-jwt), where
Lambda@Edge simply makes a [request](https://github.com/richardjkendall/cf-edge-jwt/blob/master/utils.py#L140) to [another API](https://github.com/richardjkendall/validate-jwt-api) that does not have such harsh limit on its size and can use `cryptography` without compromising security.

Another way to delegate jwt decoding would be to invoke a separate Lambda function. [Current size quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) for a standard Lambda's deployment package is 50 MB for zipped archive and 250 MB for unzipped package, so you can easily use `cryptography` with `authlib` or `pyjwt` there. Please mind that invoking Lambda this way would be synchronous. You probably would also have to add `"lambda:InvokeFunction"` permission.

```py
import json
from boto3 import client as boto3_client

lambda_client = boto3_client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # ...
    response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName="another_lambda_",
        InvocationType='Event', # or 'RequestResponse' for sync request/response
        Payload=json.dumps(your_payload)
    )
    # ...
```

Comment: Turns out the pyjwt only added up to 50KB of additional packages. PyJWT therefore seems much more of a lightweight library.

Comment: However, with the cryptography library the size went back up to 6MB. Need to look elsewhere for a solution.

Comment: As I said, if you need `cryptography` dependency just delegate heavy lifting to another API, like in the second solution.

Comment: @Frankster I expanded the second solution by adding an exaple how to delegate jwt encoding/decoding to a standard Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

The [python-jose](https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose) module is small enough to be packaged into < 1MB function for Lambda@Edge. It has its own python-native implementation of RSA etc therefore does not require the `cryptography` dependency